# Comment only once per node

Tags: comments, forms

I'm trying to get my users to post only once on each Product node... I'm kind of new to hooks and I'm not sure what else should I use for this.

What is the drupal way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Comment limit](http://drupal.org/project/comment_limit) module.

> Limits how many comments a user may post on a node.
>   Adjustable on a per node type basis.
>
> This module can be handy for instance when comments are used as "Reviews" and "Ratings" for products and a user may only review and rate a product once.